# reading and printing multi objects json file in linux

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a multi objects (millions) json file which I want to extract the values of some keys and print them. This should be very fast.

the file looks like:

```
{"a": "text", "b": 2, "c": "text", "d": "text", "e": "text", "f": "text", "g": "N", "h": "text", "i": 11, "j": "text", "k": ""}
{"a": "text", "b": 2, "c": "text", "d": "text", "e": "text", "f": "text", "g": "N", "h": "text", "i": 11, "j": "text", "k": ""}
```

the code I wrote looks like:

```
import sys, json; 
data=json.load(sys.stdin) ; 
print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(data.get('a',''),data.get('b',''),data.get('c','')))
```

when I run this with `head -1 file.txt | extract.py` it works, but with `cat file.txt | extract.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 581)
```

I choose python as it looks like the one with the best performance, but if you know other language which you think is faster - please post your answer as well.

the idea in the end is to do something like:

```
cat file.txt | extract.py | <farther_processing...>
```

**Update:**
after the help from @syntonym and @oguzismail `python` and `jq` working for me, those are the results for small 150k file:

```
jq -r '[.a, .b] | @tsv' file.txt:
real    0m7.939s
user    0m6.059s
sys     0m0.945s

python (as the suggested solution):
real    0m2.374s
user    0m2.327s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The end solution will be used on an hourly schedule for dozens of files (1m-5g) each hour.

Comment: [tag:jq] is the tool you're looking for.

Comment: @oguzismail `jq -r '[.a, .b] | @tsv' file.txt` is the best/fastest option with `jq`?

Comment: Best? Yes, it is clear and idiomatic. Fastest? No idea.

Comment: On my laptop a 150.000 line file takes around 0.5 seconds and a 3.500.000 lines file takes around 10 seconds with both solutions (jq and python). For a dozen files that's around 2 minutes, with your numbers (factor 4) something around 8 minutes. If it's hourly scheduled that seems fast enough for me?

Comment: Well the real file contain much more keys and longer values. maybe that's why 150k for me took 2s in python. plus I'm using a server not laptop. And it is for dozens (80-90) files not 10. In any case I was just curious to know if python is the fastest. Maybe I will try awk as well

Comment: If you find good solutions with awk/sed/perl you can post self answers so that others can also see which works best. I've tried another version with nim-lang which takes 15 seconds, but my nim skills are nearly not existent. My guess is that the json parsing is the bottleneck, so if you can circumvent that you should be much faster (e.g. only a regex maybe?). [This link](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-json-library/) compares different python json libraries for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input file each line is a valid json document - but the file itself is not. Thus you need to process each line separately:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    data=json.load(line) ; 
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(data.get('a',''),data.get('b',''),data.get('c','')))
```

Whether performance is acceptable depends on your use case. Python has some overhead for function calls which makes this slower than e.g. C++/rust/java, but if you only run this once a day it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: How about compare to awk/grep/perl/sed ?

Comment: Is the performance actually a problem? If you run it once a day it probably doesn't matter, and as you already have the python solution why spend time writing another one when the solution you already have is sufficient? My guess would be that awk grep and sed are all faster by maximally a factor of 5. I have a similar python script that runs in about 1 minute for 3.6 million data points, maybe something more efficient would bring that done to 20 seconds, but to me that literally makes no difference.

Comment: Actually this is critical for us. I will compare `python` with `jq`

Comment: You probably get better help if you give some details to "critical" in your question. Is this run at 100% CPU? Do you run this every minute? Do you have to process 10 Million records every hour?  Does this run on a big server? On a cluster? On a laptop?

Answer (score 0):

As you're also interested in other solutions that python, here is one solution with [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
rg -o '"a": "(\w+)", "b": (\d+), "c": "(\w+)"' -r '$1 $2 $3' FILE
```

Note that this does not parse JSON but assumes this very specific string layout. It runs in 5 seconds on a 3.500.000 lines file for me, whereas the python version above runs in 11 seconds on the same file.